# Problema ao inserir dados no banco

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Estou tentando inserir uma massa de dados no banco Mysql usando Hibernate. Porém estou com o seguinte erro:

```
18:15:30,221 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000388: Unsuccessful: INSERT INTO tb_pessoa_fisica (id,nome,cpf,telefone_comercial,telefone_residencial,telefone_celular,email,idade,data_nascimento) VALUES (92,"Zeph Damon Maddox","64871487509","(14)3523-6032","(55)8246-5275","(38)7000-8218","hymenaeos.Mauris@sodales.net",58,"2015-04-26")
18:15:30,221 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Data truncation: Data too long for column 'cpf' at row 1
```

O meu atributo está assim no java:

```
@NotBlank
@Pattern(regexp="\\d{11}", message="ATENÇÃO: Deve ser informado 11 dígitos!")
@Column(columnDefinition="char(11)", nullable=false)
private String cpf;
```

Alguém me ajuda a entender este problema e resolvê-lo?

Comment: verifique esses parametros

<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>

No persistence.xml

Comment: @Marcelo  Está assim:  <!-- language: java -->  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
   <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
   <property name="connection.pool_size" value="5" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema principal era que o hibernate não apagou esta tabela em questão, antes havia um problema de campo com um valor menor do que ele tentara inserir. Após apagar a tabela manualmente, rodei novamente e funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

18:15:30,221 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Data truncation: Data too long for column 'cpf' at row 1

Notei que a linha acima esta dando problema na coluna do CPF

A informação esta muito grande e sendo cortada(truncation). 
Veja se a sua coluna cfp esta como String? Como estão as anotações desta coluna ?

Verifique caso não encontre problemas poste a classe para verificarmos.